# How does Google redirect its search results?

Tags: google-chrome, http, google-search, http-status-code-302

I input the query `java` into the search text box on `https://www.google.com`. One result is `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)`. I get the following text by right clicking the link and selecting `Copy Link Address`.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiijvLpqvnSAhVFqY8KHU5UDyYQFghDMAk&url=%68%74%74%70%73%3a%2f%2f%65%6e%2e%77%69%6b%69%70%65%64%69%61%2e%6f%72%67%2f%77%69%6b%69%2f%4a%61%76%61%5f%28%70%72%6f%67%72%61%6d%6d%69%6e%67%5f%6c%61%6e%67%75%61%67%65%29&usg=AFQjCNEaMDPWkK-lszS-jjSYrWuKEdrmKA&bvm=bv.150729734,d.dGc

And I paste the above link to Chrome address bar. And I use `Developer Tools` to monitor the HTTP network traffic.

[image]

The first HTTP request is for the original link. And its status code is 200. How does Chrome make the following request for `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)`？I know that a HTTP response with status code `302` can make brsowers following the link in `Location` header. But how is the redirect done in this case with status code `200`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect is done because in the response of the first HTTP request ([https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j...](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiijvLpqvnSAhVFqY8KHU5UDyYQFghDMAk&url=%68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%65%6E%2E%77%69%6B%69%70%65%64%69%61%2E%6F%72%67%2F%77%69%6B%69%2F%4A%61%76%61%5F%28%70%72%6F%67%72%61%6D%6D%69%6E%67%5F%6C%61%6E%67%75%61%67%65%29&usg=AFQjCNEaMDPWkK-lszS-jjSYrWuKEdrmKA&bvm=bv.150729734,d.dGc)):

- If javascript is enabled, then the window location is navigated to `https://en.wikipedia.org/...` using script.
- If javascript is disabled, or client does not support javascript, then `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` is used to redirect to `https://en.wikipedia.org/...`

Here is the response body of the first HTTP request:

```
<script>window.googleJavaScriptRedirect=1</script>
<META name="referrer" content="origin">
<script>var n={navigateTo:function(b,a,d){if(b!=a&&b.google){if(b.google.r){b.google.r=0;b.location.href=d;a.location.replace("about:blank");}}else{a.location.replace(d);}}};n.navigateTo(window.parent,window,"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)");
</script>
<noscript>
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)'">
</noscript>
```